# UITextField Edit marker is only half shown when breaking a line

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview

In my app i have a comments area, its basically a chat.

The text input is a text view, and whenever the user presses "Return" button, The line breaks.

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView*)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString*)text {
 if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {

        return YES;

    }}
```

Problem is, until the user enters the first letter it looks like so:

[image]

I trying to force enter a space (@" ") every time the enter is pressed, and then delete it.. and ether "Hacks" i cam up with, but nothing seems to work..

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change @" " with non-breaking space symbol "\u00a0"

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView*)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString*)text {
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:@"\n\u00a0"];
        return NO;
    }
```